# Angular - How to use value from multiple checkboxes

Tags: angular, checkbox

How can I receive only checked values ​​in one variable?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check-4" name="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="check-4"><span>1</span></label>

<input type="checkbox" id="check-4" name="checkbox" value="2">
<label for="check-4"><span>2</span></label>

<input type="checkbox" id="check-4" name="checkbox" value="3">
<label for="check-4"><span>3</span></label>
```

If I checked values: 1,2

```
let temp = [1,2]
```

Comment: `(1,2)` is invalid. Probably  you mean `[1,2]` which is an array contains multiple values.

Comment: @YongShun you're right!! We will receive the selected value as an Array and convert it to an object later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each checkbox, add `(change)` event to trigger the `onChecked` method and provide its value:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check-4" name="checkbox" value="1" (change)="onChecked(1)">
```

In the `onChecked` method, implement the logic to add/remove the value from the array.

```
checkedValues: number[] = [];

onChecked(value: number) {
  let i = this.checkedValues.indexOf(value);
  if (i > -1) this.checkedValues.splice(i, 1);
  else this.checkedValues.push(value);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-faabzy?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: I solved the problem, but I can make better code after seeing this! thank you!!!!

Comment: You can also use the SelectionModel from @angular/cdk/collections
First define a property in your class like:
`selectionModel = new SelectionModel(
  true,   // multiple selection or not
  [] // initial selected values
);`
Then add to the input an event handler `(change)="selectionModel.toggle(1)"`
More info about it - https://material.angular.io/cdk/collections/overview